# Geodesics in Poincare Disk

Tags: calculus-of-variations, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

I would like to find the geodesics in the Poincare disk.
I know that the metric is  $$\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}$$ so $$s=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{1-x^2-y^2}\, dx$$ Then I try to find y(x) using the Euler-Lagrange equations. The ODE in which I end up is: $$yy'^2+xy'+y=0$$ I can't solve the above ODE.
I also tried using polar coordinates: $$s= \int \frac{\sqrt{r^2+r'^2}}{1-r^2}\,d\theta$$ but the expression I get is also not easy to handle with.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use symmetry:

1. First prove (using your ODE, if you like) that the only geodesic with a vertical tangent vector is a vertical geodesic $x(t)=$constant, $y(t) = e^{\pm t + C}$.
2. Next prove that the metric is invariant under the action of the group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acting by fractional linear transformations. For the most pedestrian was to do this, consider a fractional linear transformation on the upper half plane of the form
   $$w = \frac{az+b}{cz+d} \quad\text{(with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$, $ad-bc=1$)}
   $$
   Assign variables for the real and complex parts $z=x+iy$ and $w=x'+iy'$. Rewrite the above equation as a system of two equations in two unknowns
   $$x' = f(x,y), \qquad y' = g(x,y)
   $$
   and prove that
   $$\frac{(dx')^2 + (dy')^2}{(y')^2} = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}
   $$
   There are probably slicker ways to do this.
3. One should also prove that the fractional linear action of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ acts transitively on points and on unit tangent vectors in the upper half plane. Transitivity on unit tangent vectors at $z=i$ is proved using the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{pmatrix}$$
   which represents a rotation of the unit tangent circle at $z=i$ by  the angle $\theta/2$. Transitivity on points is proved by setting $z=i$, choosing $w$ arbitrarily, and finding $a,b,c,d$.
4. Finally, transform the equations for vertical geodesics in part 1 using the factional linear transformation in part 2. This will give you the general equations for geodesics.

Comment: To prove that *every* geodesic can be obtained in this way, one has to know that $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ is the entire isometry group of the Poincaré disk

Comment: Right. Or, it's enough to know that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on the unit tangent bundle of upper half space.

Comment: @Lee Mosher Thank you for your answer. I would like though to find them using only calculus of variations.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm aware this is quite an old answer, but could you expand your 3 steps in a full proof? This seems like a particularly clean approach, but I'm afraid most of us will not be able to interpolate between your points and come up with a decent proof :)

Comment: @LeeMosher The solution $(C_1, e^{\pm t +C})$ looks more like a solution you found in the upper half plane model?

Comment: @ArcticChar: Yes. This question keeps coming up now and then, and I notice you linked to it from another recent version, so I've filled this answer out a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

$$y = \pm i \sqrt{2} x $$

Is a solution. It can be motivated (without the use of any assumptions) through a lot of work, but I'm trying to first see if using it I can find a general form, Namely I'm trying to find a general $f$ such that if

$$ r(r')^2 + xr' + r = 0$$

then

$$ f(r)(f(r'))^2 + xf(r)r' + f(r) = 0 $$

Your equation is also equivalent to

$$ (w')^2 + 2xw' + w = 0$$

where $w = y^2$